# Not able to extract urls from HTML BeautifulSoup object

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am looking to extract following url "https://mania.bg/p/pulover-alexander-mcqueen-p409648" from html (BeautifulSoup object) named urls that looks like:

```html
[<a class="product sellout product-sellout float-left status-1" data-id="409648" data-producturl="https://mania.bg/p/pulover-alexander-mcqueen-p409648" data-status="1" href="https://mania.bg/p/pulover-alexander-mcqueen-p409648"> <div class="product-hover clearfix prevent-flicker"><div class="module-icons favourite tooltip" data-id="409648" data-title=" Любима находка на 24 клиент/и. "> <img alt="" class="favourite-product like-product unactivated" data-id="409648" src="dist/assets/icon_favourite_off.png"/></div> <div class="campaign" style="color: #FFF;background-color: #000000;"> NIGHT </div> <div class="profit-icons-wrapper clearfix"> </div> <div class="product-basic-info"> <div class="image-wrapper"> <img alt="Пуловер Alexander McQueen" class="front" data-url="https://media.mania.bg/product/048/409648/300/pulover-alexander-mcqueen-2.jpg" src="https://media.mania.bg/product/048/409648/300/pulover-alexander-mcqueen-1.jpg" title="Пуловер Alexander McQueen - Mania"> </img></div> <div class="clearfix brand-line"> <div class="brand float-left text-uppercase">Alexander McQueen</div> <div class="size float-right">S</div> </div> </div> <div class="prices-section"> <div class="prices-inner-section"> <div class="price-wrapper clearfix"> <div class="price-title text-uppercase float-left"> Начална цена </div> <div class="price old"> <span>98.00</span> <span class="currency">лв.</span> </div> </div> <div class="price-wrapper clearfix"> <div class="discount price-title text-uppercase float-left"> -40% </div> <div class="price old"> <span>58.80</span> <span class="currency">лв.</span> </div> </div> <div class="price-wrapper clearfix"> <div class="discount price-title text-uppercase float-left" style="color: #FFF;background-color: #000000"> -40% </div> <div class="price"> <span>35.28</span> <span class="currency">лв.</span> </div> </div> </div> </div> </div> <div class="button button-auction buy-now text-center float-left tooltip prevent-popup-close" data-id="409648" data-title="Може да добавите този продукт към количката.">ДОБАВЯМ<img alt="" class="bag-icon" src="dist/assets/icon_bag_button.svg"> </img></div> </a>]
```

With following code:

```
for num in range(len(urls)):
    url = urls[num - 1].a['href']
```

I also tried to use:

```
url = urls[num - 1].a['data-producturl']
```

I get "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable" as url is None.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import requests
import bs4

url = 'https://mania.bg/p/pulover-alexander-mcqueen-p409648'
data = requests.get(url)

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(data.text,'html.parser')

urls = soup.find_all('a', attrs={'class': 'product sellout product-sellout float-left status-1'})
for num in range(len(urls)):
    url = urls[num]['href']
    print(url)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Here's an example:https://github.com/yiyedata/simplified-scrapy-demo/tree/master/doc_examples

```
from simplified_scrapy.simplified_doc import SimplifiedDoc
html ='''
[<a class="product sellout product-sellout float-left status-1" data-id="409648" data-producturl="https://mania.bg/p/pulover-alexander-mcqueen-p409648" data-status="1" href="https://mania.bg/p/pulover-alexander-mcqueen-p409648"> <div class="product-hover clearfix prevent-flicker"><div class="module-icons favourite tooltip" data-id="409648" data-title=" Любима находка на 24 клиент/и. "> <img alt="" class="favourite-product like-product unactivated" data-id="409648" src="dist/assets/icon_favourite_off.png"/></div> <div class="campaign" style="color: #FFF;background-color: #000000;"> NIGHT </div> <div class="profit-icons-wrapper clearfix"> </div> <div class="product-basic-info"> <div class="image-wrapper"> <img alt="Пуловер Alexander McQueen" class="front" data-url="https://media.mania.bg/product/048/409648/300/pulover-alexander-mcqueen-2.jpg" src="https://media.mania.bg/product/048/409648/300/pulover-alexander-mcqueen-1.jpg" title="Пуловер Alexander McQueen - Mania"> </img></div> <div class="clearfix brand-line"> <div class="brand float-left text-uppercase">Alexander McQueen</div> <div class="size float-right">S</div> </div> </div> <div class="prices-section"> <div class="prices-inner-section"> <div class="price-wrapper clearfix"> <div class="price-title text-uppercase float-left"> Начална цена </div> <div class="price old"> <span>98.00</span> <span class="currency">лв.</span> </div> </div> <div class="price-wrapper clearfix"> <div class="discount price-title text-uppercase float-left"> -40% </div> <div class="price old"> <span>58.80</span> <span class="currency">лв.</span> </div> </div> <div class="price-wrapper clearfix"> <div class="discount price-title text-uppercase float-left" style="color: #FFF;background-color: #000000"> -40% </div> <div class="price"> <span>35.28</span> <span class="currency">лв.</span> </div> </div> </div> </div> </div> <div class="button button-auction buy-now text-center float-left tooltip prevent-popup-close" data-id="409648" data-title="Може да добавите този продукт към количката.">ДОБАВЯМ<img alt="" class="bag-icon" src="dist/assets/icon_bag_button.svg"> </img></div> </a>]
'''
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
urls = doc.selects('a.product sellout product-sellout float-left status-1')
print ([(url.href,url['data-producturl']) for url in urls])
```

Result:

```
[('https://mania.bg/p/pulover-alexander-mcqueen-p409648', 'https://mania.bg/p/pulover-alexander-mcqueen-p409648')]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I would really lie to avoid adding another package. The other answer I've got worked.

Comment: It's ok^------^

Answer (score 0):

`find_all` already gives you the list of `a` elements; you just need to get the href from each.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://mania.bg/p/pulover-alexander-mcqueen-p409648'

r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

for a in soup.find_all(
        'a',
        attrs={'class':
               'product sellout product-sellout float-left status-1'}):
    print(a['data-producturl'])
```

Comment: Correct, I am editing the question, as this code soup.find_all(
        'a',
        attrs={'class':
               'product sellout product-sellout float-left status-1'}) actually returns the html listed. I need to extract the url from it.

Comment: Edited my answer according to new requirements.

Comment: If that still does not give you the data you want then you'll need to define what `url` you want.

Comment: code looks like this now and works like a charm :) urls = csoup.find_all('a', attrs={'class': 'product sellout product-sellout float-left status-1'}, href=True)
                    
                    for num in range(len(urls)):
                        url = urls[num-1]['href']